# How to get Search Console email notifications only from certain property?

Tags: google-search-console

I have an email address, which is the owner of multiple Search Console properties. Usually all GSC notifications are off.

Now I want to get GSC notifications only from one certain property. But after I activate email notifications (user settings → email preferences), I get notifications from all properties. Is there a way to setup notifications based on property?

Answer (score 2):

THis is not possible.

> **Managing your email preferences**
> Manage which types of emails Search Console should send to you. Enable or disable emails of specific types, or disable all email messages. Email preferences are set at the user level, not the property level, so you can manage only your own email preferences.
>
> The settings here apply to all of your properties; for example, unsubscribing from the "New owner" email will prevent sending of the new owner email for any of your properties. **You cannot specify different email settings for different properties.**

From [support.google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/140528?hl=en-GB)

You can, however, unsubscribe to certain types of notifications.  To do this, when you receive an email, click on the unsubscribe link there.  Then you will not get any notifications of that type for all of your properties.